# Some details of winter bash page in Spanish.

Tags: support, languages, winter-bash

I speak Spanish, so when I entered to the winter bash page, it was Spanish by default (I don't know why, but that's not the point). It isn't because of google traductor; in the end of the page I have a button that says **view all text in English** and it has some details, so I want to send a mail to advise for the typos. To what mail I have to send them?

Comment: Based on [this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/288311#288312) and [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/271238) on meta.SE it seems that makings a separate post about the typos or incorrect translations might be way to go.

Comment: So I add it as a question to the meta.SE?

Comment: That's what I understood from the posts I linked.